# Meteor template named "events" not rendering. Reserved?

Tags: templates, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I tried naming my template "events", and routing it via the iron-router with:

```
Router.map ->

    @route 'events',
        path: '/events'

    @route 'venues',
        path: '/venues'
```

The "venues" route renders fine, but not the "events" route. It's just blank. This is my layout template:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> header}}
  {{> yield}}
  {{> footer}}
</template>
```

And the "events" template is simply:

```
<template name="events">
  <h1>Events</h1>
</template>
```

Does anyone know why? Is "events" reserved for template-names in Meteor?
And if so, is there any kind of work-around except changing the name?

Thanks guys

Comment: You can change the name of the template without changing the path or name of the route. Also +1 to what @HubertOG said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there was a workaround, using such name for template is guaranteed to confuse all developers multiple times – I saw this exact problem. I suggest using "shows" instead.